# PsychoPy exit fullscreen fails with Spyder

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, psychopy

I am programming an experiment with PsychoPy, but I'm using Spyder2 as an environment (much better than the Coder).

When I set the window to fullscreen

```
from psychopy import core, clock, visual, event
win = visual.Window([800,600], fullscr=True, monitor="testMonitor", units='cm')
```

I can't close it properly. Even when I call `win.close()` or `core.quit()`, the screen stayes gray. All text disappears though and I can see my mouse cursor changing, which means that the window is just a ghost. I cant even CTRL+ALT+DEL, as the screen turns black then. I have successfully found the console underneath the gray and typed "quit" which helped in the end.

How can I close the window properly without it leaving a gray screen behind? (Must be something about refreshing the window?)

Answer (score 1):

Open Spyder and go to **Tools > Preferences > Run**. Then tick "Execute in a new dedicated python console". That will kill the script once it finishes.

The problem with the default "persistent" ipython console in Spyder for the psychopy module, is that some cleanup is only done on interpreter shutdown, as far as I know.

Comment: Unfortunately core.quit() does not stop the behaviour from appearing. Your first trick though works! Thanks. So the problem seems to be the iPython-console

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:
Whever I close the fullscreen window, I start a new, non fullscreen window after that:

```
win.close()
win = visual.Window(fullscr=False)
win.close()
```

This makes the grey ghost-screen disappear and the second window can be closed with no problem.

Comment: Interesting! To keep the answer minimal, am I right that replacing the second line with ``win = visual.Window(fullscr=False)`` is sufficient?